# Why Android App crashes when attempting to start new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

So I'm trying to design the app to get to another screen with the intent, however it keeps crashing.

I'm using imageButton with an on-click-listener. I added a second java module for the destination page, a layout and added the application to the manifest file. Please let me know if you want me to make this any more informative

#### Logcat Error

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bet/com.example.bet.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.bet.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
```

I noted which line is 42

#### Main activity primary code  *Updated*

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;  //Launching other pages
import android.app.Activity; // Activity Launcher
import android.widget.ImageButton; //Image buttons
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }


}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        // / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
        //Initialize forms of the ImageButtons
        // / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
        /* Forms Button */
        ImageButton pcaButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.pcaButton);

        // / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
        //Attach the Listener (On Click Event handler)
        // / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /

        pcaButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , pcaActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

#### Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bet.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bet.pcaActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_pca" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

#### String.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">bet</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_pca">pca</string>
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
```

#### fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
android:background="@drawable/abc_ab_transparent_light_holo">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pcaButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pca1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check if `pcaButton` is null.

Comment: @digitalfresh right on target, it is. But why is it? I imported android.widget.ImageButton

Comment: Does `activity_main.xml` have a view with `@+id/pcaButton`? Also, try cleaning and rebuilding your project.

Comment: Yes but not exactly in activity_main.xml it is in its other layout file assoicated with MainActivity, fragment_main.xml (it's how studio started me with). Tried cleaning and building again, didn't do the trick. Added both files text to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `ImageButton` is defined in the fragment, you need to find it within `onCreateView` in the fragment (as it doesn't exist in the activity).

In `PlaceholderFragment`, do something like:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    // / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
    //Initialize forms of the ImageButtons
    // / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
    /* Button */
    ImageButton pcaButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.pcaButton);

    // / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
     //Attach the Listener (On Click Event handler)
    // / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / / /
    pcaButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override                                 //<-- Line 42
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , pcaActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, I just did that but I'm still getting the same error, and it is still null.
I also noticed ImageButton, View and Intent don't come off as blue on android studio, maybe it's a dependency issue. However the ide setup does notice which imported library are useless and which ones are used. P.S. MainActivity.this seems to be null too (mArguments, mView, mTarget)

Answer (score 0):

In your layout:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/pcaButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/pca1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:on="center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="some_function"
    />
```

In your class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
   public void some_function(View v){
       //Do what you want to do
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , pcaActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
```

This never fails, I prefeer this than assgin an OnclickListener and never fails

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem,although the `PlaceholderFragment` was `static` by default and couldn't let me use `MainActivity.this` as it's not `static`,Even if i found a way to use it,it showed me a `NullpointerException`.Try changing `MainActivity.this` with `getActivity`()

Comment: Oh,and get view by ImageButton pcaButton = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pcaButton);   It worked for me

Answer (score -2):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

maybe extends Activity and not ActionBarActivity?